# SQL selecting data from two tables in two different mdb files

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use [MDB Viewer Plus](http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm) to handle mdb database files. The problem with the following SQL query:

```
select `0bok`.bk AS bookTitle, `book`.page from [database=E:\feqh\main.mdb].`0bok`, [database=E:\feqh\31620.mdb].`book` where `0bok`.bkid = 31620
```

I want to perform select from two different tables in the two different database files. The above query returns the following error:

> Error: Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or
>   incomplete information provided.

I tried to prefix database with ; `[;database=E:\feqh\main.mdb]` but also it generate errors. I inspired this solution from this [Microsoft official article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113701)

Comment: inside MSAccess it works this way `FROM [E:\feqh\main.mdb].[0bok]`

Comment: @4dmonster unfortunately id does not work. I used `IN` clause before but with select from one mdb file.